# Not getting data from database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

When I try to login then I am getting hibernate log message.

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@Column(name = "username", unique = true, 
    nullable = false, length = 45)
private String username;
@Column(name = "password", 
        nullable = false, length = 100)
private String password;
@Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
private boolean enabled;
/*@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)*/
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="user_roles",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_name", referencedColumnName="username")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);
public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
    return this.userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}
getter and setter
```

UserRole.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class UserRole {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String role;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="user_roles", 
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_name", referencedColumnName="username")}
)
private Set<User> userRoles;
 public Set<User> getUserRoles() {
    return userRoles;
}

public void setUserRoles(Set<User> userRoles) {
    this.userRoles = userRoles;
}
getter and setter
```

I have login form and used  spring security with hibernate for authentication and authorization. When I try to login with username and password as in the db then I get error saying invalid username and password. And hibernate log message in console:

```
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
select
    user0_.username as username1_2_,
    user0_.enabled as enabled2_2_,
    user0_.password as password3_2_ 
from
    users user0_ 
where
    user0_.username=?
Hibernate: 
select
    userrole0_.user_name as user_nam2_1_0_,
    userrole0_.role_id as role_id1_1_0_,
    userrole1_.id as id1_0_1_,
    userrole1_.role as role2_0_1_ 
from
    user_roles userrole0_ 
inner join
    roles userrole1_ 
        on userrole0_.role_id=userrole1_.id 
where
    userrole0_.user_name=?
```

I am adding SpringSecurityConfig.java and I haved used hash password. Is that causing the problem ?

```
Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
    .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
    .usernameParameter("username")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .and().csrf()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
  }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a stack trace?

Is the database connection working?

The passwords in the database are hashed.

Comment: Sorry I don't have stack trace. Yes the database connection in working well and the password are hashed and I have used PasswordEncoder